# Is it possible to achieve something like HOC with classes - without classes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to do something like:

```
<SomeProvider showConfirm={showConfirm}>
    {props.showConfirm()
    ? (<confirmActionComponent />)
    : (<chooseActionComponent />)}
</SomeProvider>
```

Inside of `chooseActionComponent` I want to be able to access `showConfirm` or another value in a deep nested child component to update some value in the parent and have `confirmActionComponent` show.

I know how to achieve this using `class` which tends to involve `this` and `bind` at some point, and I would prefer to avoid that.

Is there any way to accomplish something like this using pure functions/components instead? Would also prefer to keep this out of Redux store.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access `showConfirm`, you simply can pass it to the child:

```
<SomeProvider showConfirm={showConfirm}>
    {props.showConfirm()
    ? (<confirmActionComponent />)
    : (<chooseActionComponent showConfirm={showConfirm} />)}
</SomeProvider>
```

---

Note following quote from React docs to inheritance:

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven't found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.

---

Anyway, I maybe have a really really dirty hack for you...
use `ref`...

```
const Child = () =>
    <div ref={(self) => {
        // get ReactDOMNode on stateless component
        const ReactDOMNode = self[Object.keys(self).filter((key) =>
            /__reactInternalInstance/g.test(key))[0]];

        // access parent props
        console.dir(ReactDOMNode
            ._hostParent
            ._currentElement
            ._owner
            ._currentElement
            .props);
    }}></div>;
```

Note: that this is not recommended and I won't recommend that, too.
I would advice you to simply pass needed parent props to the child.

```
<SomeProvider showConfirm={showConfirm}>
    {props.showConfirm()
    ? (<confirmActionComponent />)
    : (<chooseActionComponent showConfirm={showConfirm} />)}
</SomeProvider>
```

And in your `chooseActionComponent` you can:

```js
const chooseActionComponent = ({parentProps: {showConfirm}}) =>
    <div>{showConfirm}</div>;
```

Comment: Right, but that's precisely what I am trying to refactor out :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use ES6 classes to create React content.  If you would like to avoid having to repeatedly use `bind` to ensure correct scoping of methods (that use `this.setState` / `this.props`), you can **revert back to using the React API helper functions** ([*see React without ES6*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html)).

You can specifically use: [**React.createClass**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createclass) for creating React classes and HOCs.  Again, just to re-iterate this: using this alternative syntax will ***autobind*** `this` for you.